# How to get the last element from array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have this scenario, but it's not working...
Under `h1` I want to show all elements from my array and in input value I want to show the last element from my array:

```
<h1>Solutions></h1>
<%  var element = title.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <p><%= item.name%></p>
    <% }) %>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />   
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="solution subtitle" 
    value=
    <%= element.length-1 %>

    />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submite</button>
</form>
```

How can I get the last element from array using eJS?

Comment: Hi there! The last element in an array should be accessible like this: `array[array.length - 1]`. Are you trying to get the last element of the `title` or `element` array?

Comment: last elemet from title

Comment: Ok. You can access that like this: `titile[titile.length - 1]`. In the input element, that would be something like this: `<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="solution subtitle" value= <%= titile[titile.length - 1]%>`

Comment: I tried that one too but also something not working ... it's return "{" symbol in input

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("5e74c2ff6ee4a61a0ca3a2f0"), "name" : "someItem1", "__v" : 0 } { "_id" : ObjectId("5e787701e5b6955328ffce26"), "name" : "someItem2", "__v" : 0 } { "_id" : ObjectId("5e787704e5b6955328ffce27"), "name" : "someItem3", "__v" : 0 } { "_id" : ObjectId("5e787706e5b6955328ffce28"), "name" : "someItem4", "__v" : 0 }


 I want to get "someItem4" element

Comment: Can you share an example of data contained in the title array?

Comment: I did it, it work for me in this way 

  <% var { [Object.keys(title).pop()]: lastItem } = title %>
           <p ><%= (lastItem.name) %></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use like this

```
 <%= element[element.length-1] %>
```

Comment: <%= title[title.length-1] %>